# Qt Creator Git, command for checkout

Tags: git, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, git-checkout

I'm working on a Git-enabled Qt project and want to quickly check out some files from a previous commit. For this, although Qt Creator provides features for checking out another branch, apparently it doesn't provide any mechanism for checking out a commit in the same branch.

The only option suggested in Qt Creator is that I should reset `HEAD` to somewhere else and then manually get it back, which is a bit painful.

Another option would be manually I check out another commit via terminal and switch back.

Both options aren't handy and requires using external terminal.

So, my question would be: Is there any plug-in / configuration / setting preferences in Qt Creator in order to add checkout capability?

Comment: What’s wrong with using the terminal? For complex workflows, it should be much simpler than messing with UIs designed for the most common workflows.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld There's nothing wrong with. However, I'd prefer to work in one environment not repeatedly switching between Qt Creator and Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available out of the box, but I just did see it.

> Tools -> Git -> Actions on Commits...

Then, click on <kbd>Browse History...</kbd> and choose the commit you would like to go to. Afterwards, you should click <kbd>Checkout</kbd> to check it out.

For switching back:

> Tools -> Git -> Local Repository -> Branches...

And check it out your previous working branch.